# JS prototype vs closure

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript object that does something like this - using a closure to simulate private vs public functions/variables:

```
var myCoolObject = function(x, y) {

    var prop1 = "a cool prop1 value";
    var negX = x * -1;
    var negY = y * -1;
    var xyProduct = x * y;

    return {
      PublicProp1: prop1,
      getXYProduct: function() { return xyProduct; },
      getNegX: function() { return negX; },
      getNegY: function() { return negY; }
    }
}
```

I will be creating around 4000 instances of this object, and from what I am reading adding functions via the `prototype` will be more efficient than adding them as I have above (because in my example, each instance will have it's own `getXYProcust()`, `getNegX()` and `getNegY()` functions.

My question is twofold - is my approach above really "inefficient"?  I realize that inefficient is a relative term - but is this something I will likely notice.  If it is inefficient, how would I add those functions to the `prototype` of `myCoolObject`?  I tried the following:

```
myCoolObject.prototype.protoProp = "pppp";
myCoolObject.prototype.getAtMeBro = function () { return "get at me bro"; };
var myInstance = new myCoolObject(5, 10);
```

But neither `protoProp` nor 'getAtMeBro()' are properties of `myInstance` when I inspect it.

Thanks in advance for any help - I appreciate it!

Comment: How does the constructor look now? Make sure you don't return anything (or just `this`).

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question?  the constructor would look like new myCoolObject(5, 10) when I instantiate it.

Comment: No, constructor is the function used with the `new` keyword such as `function myCoolObject() {}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The best advice is to **try it and see**. In the modern JS engines, you should find that 4,000 objects are childs play and should not be a problem (provided each of them don't get *too* big). If you've got users on IE6 and older engines, be prepared for them to be able to cope with less.

   As an example, a Facebook Timeline feed requires ~4000 (3992 when I tried) DOM elements; each of these are *far* more complicated than the objects you're creating (granted, they make use of the prototype method, but they hold a *lot* more information).
2. You cannot apply the private member pattern when using `prototype`'s, because you cannot create a closure to encapsulate both. The typical pattern here is to denote a private member with a leading `_`, to *hint* at people not to use it (but of course, there is nothing stopping them from doing so).

Comment: Thanks!  I have tried it and haven't noticed much of a CPU or Memory hit, but I keep running across articles promoting the use of prototype so I am wondering if I am making a fundamental design mistake.  I will be calling the getXYProduct() function for all 4000 objects on some timer interval - about 50 seconds - which still hasn't caused much of a performance hit.   As for # 2, you are saying don't use a closure if I want to use prototype - just rename my locals to start with an _ and put threatening/scary comments in warning people not to use them?

Comment: The good thing about changing to a prototype approach should not be *too* much effort. And yes, for #2 they will end up being public methods, but your scary comment and leading `_` should put people off using them.